# Replace variables from a given string

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have a string with variables names, formatted like interpolation.

```cs
Class MailManager{
    CreateMail(){
        Mail mail = new Mail("This is the mail {name}")
    }
    class Mail{
        string header {get;set;}
        string name {get;set;}

        internal Mail(string header){
            this.header = header;
            name = "i am the mail name";
        }
        internal void FormatHeader(){
            //Do something here to evaluate variables in header
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to replace `{name}` and other variable names with variable values.

I tried with SmartFormat

```cs
 void FormatHeader(){
     header =  Smart.Format(header)
 }
```

But it throws an error `Could not evaluate the selector "name"`

I tried with reflection :

```cs
 void FormatHeader(){
      foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(header, @"{(.*?)}"))
      {
           header = header.Substring(0,m.Index) +  GetType().GetProperty(m.Groups[1].ToString()) + header.Substring(m.Index + m.Length);
      }
 }
```

But here the  `GetType().GetProperty("name")` do not find anything

Is there a way to correct one of this solution ? Or else to find another one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetType().GetProperty() only returns public properties, make your property public inorder for this to work (or you can use bindingFlags)

take a look at this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=net-5.0

Comment: I used bindingFlags, worked great : `GetType().GetProperty(m.Groups[1].ToString(), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this).ToString()`
.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something here, you can simply use `Replace`:

```cs
var sourceString = "This is the mail {name}";
var targetString = sourceString.Replace("{name}", name);
```

Comment: The thing you're missing is that they don't want to hardcode the variable names, but replace them using reflection.

Comment: @CodeCaster perhaps it's only me, but I think the OP has terribly overcomplicated this. I really don't see any need for reflection here.

Comment: I see it as a case that OP has a base class with the parsing logic, and derived classes with specific properties that the caller can assign. The caller then calls `FormatHeader()` to replace each instance of `"{propertyName}"` in the template string with the value of the named property. This can't be done at compile time, and the properties can't be known on beforehand.

Comment: _"I would like to replace {name} and other variable names with variable values"_ - they used "variable" where they meant "property" though.

Comment: @CodeCaster is right, i have dozens of properties that may be in this string. I would prefer to have an unique code block using reflection than one line per possible evaluating property. But i agree this solution is good otherwise

Answer (score 0):

That seems overly complicated, just use the String.Replace method

here is a link to the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for elaborated solution, you can try *reflection* and *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  internal void FormatHeader() {
    // Get all readable (non-indexer) properties' names and values
    Dictionary<string, object> data = GetType()
      .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static |
                     BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.GetIndexParameters().Length <= 0)
      .ToDictionary(
         p => p.Name, 
         p => p.GetValue((p.GetAccessors(true)[0].IsStatic ? null : this), 
                          Array.Empty<object>()));

    // Replace all {name} fragments to corresponing values
    header = Regex.Replace(
      header,
      @"\{\s*\p{L}[\p{L}_0-9]*\s*\}",
      m => data.TryGetValue(m.Value.Trim('{', '}', ' '), out var v) 
              ? v?.ToString() 
              : m.Value);
  }
```